# Unable to access a key value from a json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, object, key-value

I have a json as below

```
var object = {200x200: "url1", 400x400: "url2", 800x800: "url3"};
```

I stringified the object and tried to acccess "200x200". But its throwing

> undefined

```
object = JSON.stringify(object);
//object = {"200x200": "url1", "400x400": "url2", "800x800": "url3"};
```

I tried to access like this

```
object['200x200'] // got undefined
```

Any other way to access the url1 from this object ?

Comment: you can check at https://jsonlint.com/ and see that your JSON is invalid. The keys must have quotes round them.

Comment: also, if you stringify it, it its converted from an object a single string variable (with text which looks like a JSON _representation_ of the object ) and therefore, by definition, no longer has any properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you stringify it, it’s a string. You have to parse it back into an object.

```
var newObject = JSON.parse(object);
console.log(object[200x200];
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Answer (score 2):

Because you json object is wrong format:

Wrap your keys in quotes, like this: https://codepen.io/creativedev/pen/LrBOmG

```
var object = {'200x200': "url1",'400x400': "url2", '800x800': "url3"};
```

Then check:

```
console.log(object['200x200']);
```

you will get output

Answer (score 1):

you should change you object to

```
var object = {'200x200': "url1", '400x400': "url2", '800x800': "url3"};

object['200x200'] // 'url1'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can parse it:

```
object = JSON.parse(object);
```

*then* access the key:

```
let url1 = object['200x200']
```

No idea why you would stringify it in the first place though!

```
let jsonObject = JSON.stringify(object);
// instead of:
let url1 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object))['200x200']
```